# how to catch stack overflow error in golang

Tags: go, stack-overflow

Is there any way to catch stack overflow error in golang? Currently I'm using go recover() do this job(below code snippet), looks like stack overflow error can't be caught.

```
defer func() {
            if x := recover(); x != nil {
                log.Error("In recover, cought error====================", x)
            }
        }()

fn(xxx)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you see in the output is a "fatal error", not a panic.

```
fatal error: stack overflow
```

You can only use `recover()` to recover from panics. A stack overflow is a fatal error thrown by the runtime which causes the process to print a stack trace and exit.

Comment: Then how can handle this fatal error? It will cause program crash.

Comment: You can't handle it, it's supposed to crash your program. There's a problem with your program if you're hitting this error.

Comment: Unfortunately it is in a library i'm using, I want to handle it in my level. Looks like no way to do it...

Answer (score -2):

by using panic & recover, you ca achieve to catch an error in golang